# Dconf settings in ~/.config/dconf/user.d/ not loaded

Tags: dconf, gsettings

I've created valid keyfiles for configuring my Gnome terminal and placed them in `~/.config/dconf/user.d/termnial.conf` but those settings are not getting picked up by the dconf system. Is this the wrong location? Is there something else I need to enable this path as a possible location of key files?

I'm on a relatively fresh install of Ubuntu 18.10 (minimal install).

For reference, here's my keyfile:

```
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings]
new-window='<Primary>n'
close-tab='<Primary>w'
close-window='<Primary>q'
new-tab='<Primary>t'

[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:]
list=['e83a0879-55a8-457a-8ff8-1c6e16e6456c', '01d81b02-4e2d-418b-af8a-d82db5437ccd']
default='e83a0879-55a8-457a-8ff8-1c6e16e6456c'

[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:e83a0879-55a8-457a-8ff8-1c6e16e6456c]
background-color='rgb(255,255,255)'
use-theme-colors=true
use-theme-transparency=false
visible-name='Basic'
foreground-color='rgb(0,0,0)'
use-system-font=false
font='Ubuntu Mono 12'

[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:01d81b02-4e2d-418b-af8a-d82db5437ccd]
background-color='rgb(0,43,54)'
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
visible-name='Vagrant'
foreground-color='rgb(131,148,150)'
use-system-font=false
font='Ubuntu Mono 12'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually load the key files:

```
dconf load / < ~/.config/dconf/user.d/terminal.conf
```

Comment: Even if I discord this answer provides a solution, since `~/.config/dconf/user.d/` should carry default schema configurations. Would you be able to accept your answer?